# WordPress Cron to update html file once a day

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, cron

So I just realized the WordPress Cron API and its perfect for a task Im trying to solve. I need WordPress Cron to update a html file on my Multisite.
--------
Goal:
What Im trying to achieve is in my Network of sites I need the main site to use a child theme of Theme A and all subsites to use a child theme of Theme B. All subsites must then implement the header of the main site at the top of the site, including its styles, links etc.

--------
Ive been reading on how WordPress Cron works, but I have no idea on how to approach this task Im trying to solve. Im thinking I need to create a mu-plugin and hook my Cron job to Wordpress, more or less like this:

```
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'plugin_job' );
    function plugin_job(){
     //Use wp_next_scheduled to check if the event is already scheduled
     $timestamp = wp_next_scheduled( 'plugin_create_job' );

     //If $timestamp == false schedule
     if( $timestamp == false ){
           //Schedule the event for right now, then to repeat daily using the hook
           wp_schedule_event( time(), 'daily', 'plugin_create_job' );
     }
}

//Hook our function
add_action( 'plugin_create_job', 'create_job' );
function create_job(){
     //Generate html file from Mainsites header.php
}
```

I could definitely use some guidance and inputs :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say that this method is overcomplicating the issue but if you want to do it by a wp_cron job the methods you are looking for are [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) and [file_put_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php).

So you'll want to use file_get_contents to convert the header file into a string, save that string as a variable and then use file_put_contents to write that string to an html file somewhere on your server.

```
function create_job(){
    //Generate html file from Mainsites header.php
    $header_contents = file_get_contents( get_template_directory_uri() . '/header.php' );

    //If the header contains any information write to file
    if( $header_contents ) {
        file_put_contents( 'path/to/html/file.html', $header_contents );
    }
}
```

Two other points... wp_cron is pretty terible and when possible should be [replaced with a real server CRON job](http://www.iceablethemes.com/optimize-wordpress-replace-wp_cron-real-cron-job/).

And also, don't forget to destroy the cron schedule on plugin deactivation...

```
function myplugin_deactivation() {
    wp_clear_scheduled_hook( 'plugin_create_job' );
}

register_deactivation_hook( __FILE__, 'myplugin_deactivation' );
```

Alternatively just remove the header.php file of all your child themes, then all calls for get_header will retrieve the `header.php` file from the parent theme.

Another way to approach this would be create a function in your parent theme's functions file that simply outputs the contents of the themes header of theme A...

```
function mysite_get_custom_header() {
    return file_get_contents( get_theme_root_uri() . '/child-theme-A/header.php' );
}
```

Then replace all instances of `get_header()` in Child Theme B to...

```
echo mysite_get_custom_header();
```

Hope that helps

Regards

Dan

Comment: Hey @danbahrami - Thanks so much for your input! Can you expand on why its overcomplicated? I thought this would be a way to put less requests and traffic on the server? I would love to hear what approach you think is the right!

Comment: @MacLuc you're welcome. could you better explain the situation. Are the subsites of your multisite network be feeding off the same theme as your mainsite and therefor using the same header.php file anyway?

Comment: Im expanding the situation more in my post now. Thanks.

Comment: In the goal section now. Thanks.

Comment: @MacLuc added a few more solutions to my original answer. You're not really saving any requests by doing it with wp_cron, a call to an html file is going to cost basically as much to a call to a php file and all external resources are going to have to be loaded whatever way you do it so the last few methods I give are just simpler and the poor sod who clicks on your site for the first time in the day wont have to load the header twice.

Comment: Your last suggestion seems good - but can i call the function of parent theme A (parent main site theme) in the child theme B (subsites theme)?

Comment: Sure, functions files of child themes are loaded in addition to the functions file of the parent theme. It may be worth reading up on the codex [link](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) about the hierarchy of child themes. Is there a reason you can't use the header of the parent theme for both child themes? that method seems the most Wordpress native method.

Comment: aha - of course. get_file_contents() function is not a predefined function?

Comment: file_get_contents() is a function built into the core of PHP.

Comment: I get 'Call to undefined function get_file_contents()'

Comment: thats because it's file_get_contents() not get_file_contents()

Comment: Lol sorry, didn't realise i got it wrong in my answer, have ammended the my answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71080/discussion-between-mac-luc-and-danbahrami).